# Is Google Translate transcription scheme of English words suitable?

Tags: phonetics, phonology, transcription

They use indications of long vowels and in general very appealing compared to weird IPA. On the other hand, their transcription of Russian is wrong and I would say, unsuitable.

For instance, in their system,

need = [nēd]

make = [māk]

blue = [blo͞o]

girl = [gərl]

hire = [hīr]

hair = [hi(ə)r]

here = [hi(ə)r] as well

Comment: As you've yourself discovered well, machine translation is far from perfect even if it's from Google. See for example, http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=30686 . I'm not sure if this question is strictly on-topic, so I'm not leaving an answer.

Comment: @M.A.R. Google Translate has a few features aside from the actual machine translation part.  These include multi-language input and transcription.  In this case, Anixx is asking about how the sounds of the language are written down and not the quality of the machine translation itself.

Comment: Ahh, yeah. That was a misunderstanding on my part. Considering that we have a canonical question about spell-checkers, I don't see why this shouldn't be on-topic.

Comment: You might check out the difference between *translation*, *transliteration* and *transcription*.

Comment: Adding an example or two to define your concern would be helpful. As written, the only real answer to your question would be that Google Translate isn't so accurate, for whatever reason or justification. It should be off-topic though if the focus is on Russian language issues.

Comment: @M.A.R. this question IS NOT about translation!

Comment: Yes, that was clarified by the comment from Snail. It was a misunderstanding on my part, as I said.

Comment: I'm unable to see this transcription system in use on the google translate site. In fact, I can't see any transcription used for languages in the latin script. I do see transcriptions for Russian text.  That may be due to my language settings.  Where do you see this transcription?

Comment: @James K http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/17/0214/h_1487108908_7399414_852f186c81.png

Answer (score 3):

You ask is it "suitable". It does have a purpose, but may not be suitable for you.

English is sometimes taught (to young native speakers) as having long and short vowel sounds, for example the "short a" [æ] in "ban" compared with the "long a" [eɪ] in "bane". You will notice that the "long a" isn't at all a longer version of the short a, but a dipthong. However the concept is useful when learning spelling. The origin of these sounds in in the "Great Vowel Shift" of Middle English.

The notion of a long and short "a" sound is quite ingrained. I've known people who found it very hard to accept that the "long a" sound was actually formed of two vowels that are closer to "e" and "i". So to indicate "make" [meɪk] they write the "long a" sound as ā. A similar scheme is used on Mirriam Webster, and seems to be more common in US dictionaries.

This may be surprising to a speaker of Russian, who doesn't have the notion of the long a = [eɪ]. And since they don't seem to show the pronunciation to English speakers, the system looks like a doubtful choice. IPA is much better, for those who know it, and language learners are more likely to know IPA than the average. IPA is less useful to English speakers, who want an indication of the pronunciation.

The actual transcriptions look accurate to me, with the exception of hair.

The transcriptions of Russian are different. They are an attempt to represent the Russian sounds in latin script to English speakers. It seems to be (based on?) the [BGN/PCGN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGN/PCGN_romanization_of_Russian) scheme, intended to be intuitive for English speakers.

Comment: Based on what you said (native speakers have hard time realizing long a is a diphtong) it seems a good scheme, reflecting the "internal" perception of the language.